# How to rewrite https to http for a specific url?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, ssl, https

I'm seeking help with an issue, basically my entire ecommerce website runs on HTTPS with wordpress but I have recently become affiliated with ebay.

However when I try to display their products on my site using a HTTPS page none of the images show and I get this error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONS https://thumbs2.ebaystatic.com/m/mPA8yaCHEhocIoW2TdC-0hQ/140.jpg

I'm trying to change (https example.com/shop/ebay-shop/) to (http example.com/shop/ebay-shop/)
so that the images are displayed correctly. Unless anyone knows how I can make the images load without having to redirect to http?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the top of the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^shop/ebay-shop/ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Note, you'll need to be careful with any wordpress plugins or settings that will attempt to re-redirect such a request *back* to https. If that happens, you'll end up with a redirect loop.

Comment: Nope it didn't work? 

I can't even access the link shop/ebay-shop/ by typing http into my browser because it's already being redirected to https.

In my general settings for wordpress I have told it that wordpress and the website are located at https. 

I had to do this because when I was adding items to the cart from the homepage on http and then going to cart/checkout on https the items were vanishing. 

Only way i could make the cart/checkout work properly is to use https everywhere. But with the affiliate page I don't need to use https as it's just a portal through the the actual vendor.